# Params with angular form submit

Tags: forms, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to set up dummy form with Angular. I have the form set up but I'd like to fake params sent and see the outcome. I think it's called serializing params.

Please consider the following code on success `$scope.message = "Message sent " + $scope.formData`

Currently it returns `Message sent [object Object]` where I'd like it to return params sent like `Message sent {"order": ["company": "test", "phone": "1111"]}`

Here is the full code

```
angular.module("app").controller "ContactController", ($scope, $http) ->
  $scope.formData = {}

  $scope.processForm = ->
    console.log $scope.formData

    $http(
      method: "POST"
      url: 'process.php'
      data: $scope.formData
    ).success( (data) ->
      # if successful, bind success message to message
      $scope.message = "Message sent " + $scope.formData
      $scope.formData = ''
    ).error (status) ->
      console.log "An error occured processign form"
      # if not successful, bind errors to error variables
      $scope.errorFirstName = data.errors.firstName
      $scope.errorLastName = data.errors.lastName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually fairly simple. When you call `toString()` on a object (what you're doing there), instead of being helpful, JavaScript returns `[object Object]`.
This is fairly easy to remedy, just change the `$scope.formData` to `JSON.stringify($scope.formData)`. Thus:

```
$scope.message = "Message sent " + JSON.stringify($scope.formData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Zeke's answer is a lot simpler than mine.  I was going to suggest using a function like this to turn a JavaScript object into a JSON String:

```
function objToJSONString (obj) {
    var str = '';
    for (var p in obj) {
            str += "\"" + p + "\":\"" + obj[p] + "\",";
    }
    // remove last comma
    if(str.length > 0){
        str = str.substr(0,str.length-1)
    }
    return '{' + str + '}';
}
```

This function is not without it's imperfections, though; as it won't deal with nested objects.

Comment: So instead of using a JSON encoder you wrote one. Nice.

Comment: @ZekeSonxx Yes, it appears so. If I had known about the JSON Stringify method you mentioned; I probably would have saved myself some time.